# C++ vector with std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

my function looks like this:

```
bool getPair(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>>Cards) {
std::sort(Cards.begin(), Cards.end(), Cardsort);
std::map<unsigned short, int>Counter;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    Counter[Cards[i][0]];
for (const auto& val : Counter) {
    if (val.second == 2)
        return true;
}
return false;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using `std::map` incorrectly, I basically have the vector setup like so:

```
{{2,0},{3,0},{4,1},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0}}
```

where the first number represents value, the second represents card suit. I realize now I should have used an object which may have made this problem less complicated but now I'm trying to use `std::map` to count how many times the value shows up and if it shows up two times, it show return true (in the vector it would return true at the 3) but I don't think I'm using `std::map` properly

I want to see if Cards has more than one of the same variable in Cards[i][0], I do not care about duplicates in Cards[i][1]

Comment: You might have meant `Counter[Cards[i][0]]++;` As written, you insert a bunch of `{key, 0}` pairs into the map.

Comment: What is your actual question? If you want to check for duplicates in a sorted container, use [`std::adjacent_find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/).

Comment: I'm trying to find how many times each number shows up in my two dimensional matrix table and if they show up more than once, return true

Comment: Try using std::map's insert function and use std::pair to insert the values in your first for loop: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

Comment: for insert, will that increment that key+value? I want to handle cases where there's more than just duplicate pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here´s my suggestion.

Some remarks:

- why use two loops? You already have the map entry to check, since you want to increase it, so you can check for doubles aka pairs in the counting loop. No need for a second run. This way it´s much less expensive.
- I changed the vector parameter to const&. It´s a very bad idea to pass such a thing by value, at least I can´t see why that could be appropriate in that case
- I left out the sorting thingy, can´t see for what end it´s needed, just reinsert it, if necessary. Sorting is very expensive.
- you are right in the fact that std:: containers do not need initialization, they are proper initialized, the allocator calls the constructor of new elements, event for e.g. `int` thats one reason why e.g. int got a default constructor syntax and you can write funny thingies like `auto a = int();`.
- accessing nonexistent keys of a map simply creates them
- using a set and counting will definitely not yield better performance

I think the code is pretty easy to read, here you are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

bool getPair(const std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>>& cards) {
    std::map<unsigned short, int> counts;
    for(const auto& n : cards) {
        if(++counts[n[0]] == 2)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>> cards1 = {{2,0},{3,0},{4,1},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0}};
   std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>> cards2 = {{1,0},{2,0},{4,1},{3,0},{5,0},{7,0},{6,0}};
   std::cout << getPair(cards1) << "\n";
   std::cout << getPair(cards2) << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Edit: 
Quote of the [C++14 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) regarding access to not existing members of std::map, just for the sake of completeness:

**23.4.4.3 map element access [map.access]**
**T& operator[](const key_type& x);**

- Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, T()) into the map.
- Requires: key_type shall be CopyInsertable and mapped_type shall be DefaultInsertable into
  *this.
- Returns: A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to x in *this.
- Complexity: Logarithmic.23.4.4.3 map element access

Comment: I went with your solution because it fixed some bugs I hadn't anticipated, heh.

Answer (score 2):

Tested this and works. Highlighted the fix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool getPair(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>>Cards) {
std::sort(Cards.begin(), Cards.end());
std::map<unsigned short, int>Counter;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    Counter[Cards[i][0]]++;   // ++++++++++++++++++ need to alter the value!
for (const auto& val : Counter) {
    if (val.second == 2)
        return true;
}
return false;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    // {{2,0},{3,0},{4,1},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0}}
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>> c = {{2,0},{3,0},{4,1},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0}};
    std::cout << getPair(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you address uninitialized variables in Counter, and then you don't really do anything with it (and why do you run till 6 instead of Cards.size()? Your array has size 7 BTW. Also why there is some kind of sort there? You don't need it.):

```
std::map<unsigned short, int>Counter;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     Counter[Cards[i][0]];
```

They might set the uninitialized variable automatically at 0 or they might not - it depends on the implementation as it is not specified as far as I am aware (in Debug they do set it to 0 but I doubt about the Release version). You'll need to rewrite the code as follows to make it work 100% in all circumstances:

```
std::map<unsigned short, int> Counter;
for (int i = 0; i < (int)Cards.size(); i++)
{
    unsigned short card = Cards[i][0];

    auto itr = Counter.find(card);
    if(itr == Counter.end())
         Counter[card] = 1;
    else
         itr->second++;
}
```

I would recommend to use std::set for this task:

```
std::set<unsigned short> Counter;
for (int i = 0; i < (int)Cards.size(); i++)
{
    unsigned short card = Cards[i][0];
    if(Counter.count(card)>0)
    {
          return true;
    }
    Counter.insert(card);
}
return false;
```